# How To Find Peaks In Acceleration Magnitude Swift

Tags: swift, accelerometer

I am trying to find when the magnitude of phone acceleration peaks and also count the number of peaks.  This is my current code but it doesn't work as I want it to. It just counts when the magnitude goes above a certain value.

```
func outputAccelData(acceleration: CMAcceleration) {

    let x = acceleration.x
    let y = acceleration.y
    let z = acceleration.z

    let magnitude = sqrt( (pow(x, 2.0)) + (pow(y, 2.0)) + (pow(z, 2.0)) )

    if magnitude > 1.6 {

        Count += 1

    }

    self.countLabel.text = "\(Count)"

}
```

Thanks